# Can I leave a second, 2 spike phalaenopsis orchid attached to the parent plant for now?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, orchids

I meant to detach and plant the second phalaenopsis plant,which is growing high up on the original spike, but now it has two spikes of its own, and I’m not sure what is best for mom and baby.  See photo.  Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? No.

Answer (score 7):

Wow! Why do my orchids never do that? ;-)

As you can read, I have no hands on experience with this, but I know this phenomenon. It is called a Keiki, a baby orchid. The baby is a clone of its mother. As you can see, your Keiki has leafs and roots already, and even starts to produce these canes for flowers. I say your Keiki is ready to live on its own.

You can remove it from the mother cane. Full instructions are found on internet, [here](https://www.sundaygardener.net/orchids-how-to-remove-and-pot-a-keiki/) is one example. Use special orchid potting 'soil'.